# Is it best to freeze meat pies before or after baking?

Tags: meat, freezing, pie

I'm making Tourtiere meat pies which will be frozen.  should I bake first and then freeze or freeze before baking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there special considerations for making a pie with the express intention of freezing?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/are-there-special-considerations-for-making-a-pie-with-the-express-intention-of)

Comment: There's no real difference in the answer to this question than the one I've linked, even though the was about fruit pie. My answer deals with some aspects (bake lightly before cooking to make it more robust) while others address other aspects (reheat from frozen to avoid sogginess).

Answer (score 2):

After checking with two Bloggers I trust, you can freeze first or freeze after cooking. It depends on your needs, if you want it to be ready super fast when you want it, cook first and then freeze, reheating will be quicker than cooking from frozen. If it doesn't matter, then go with whatever seems like a better option to you.

Here were my sources:

http://www.simplebites.net/how-to-makeclassic-tourtiere-qubec-pork-pie/
http://hilahcooking.com/tourtiere/